# Coded UI Playback - error thrown when entering text in particular textbox (w/ javaScript filtering keystrokes)

Tags: javascript, .net, coded-ui-tests

I'm just starting to write some coded-ui tests, and I have run into a problem during playback when I try to enter a value into a textbox which is constrained to only numeric (decimal) values via a javaScript function.   I've identified the script as the "culprit" because the test runs successfully when it is disabled.

The value I've entered in the test is legitimate per the constraints of the function, so I don't understand why the exception is being thrown when the test runner enters it.  Can anyone offer any insight?   The javascript function seems to work for our purposes, so it would seem unfortunate to have to remove it just to make the automated tests work.

Here are some more details:

My test is fairly straight-forward.   I'm finding 2 textbox controls and verifying that the proper validation message appears when a value is missing from the first.  Setting the OrderIdTextBox.Text works, but setting the AmountTextBox.Text throws the exception (when the js function below is enabled):

```
[TestMethod]
public void Should_show_validation_error_if_orderId_is_missing()
{
    _page.OrderIdTextBox.Text = "";
    if (_page.AmountTextBox.Exists)
    {
        _page.AmountTextBox.Text = "10.00";
    }
    Mouse.Click(SubmitButton);
    Assert.AreEqual(true, _page.OrderIdValidationSpan.Exists);
}
```

This is the javascript on the page which filters out unacceptable keystrokes:

```
$(document).on('keydown', ".number", function (event) {
    // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter, and decimal
    if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 || event.keyCode == 110 || event.keyCode == 190 ||
    // Allow: Ctrl+A
            (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) ||
    // Allow: home, end, left, right
            (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
        // let it happen, don't do anything
        return;
    }
    else {
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if (event.shiftKey || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

And here is the exception that's thrown when my test tries to set AmountTextBox value during playback.

```
    Test method  (namespace snipped).Should_show_validation_error_if_orderId_is_missing threw exception: 
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.PlaybackFailureException: Cannot perform 'SetProperty of Text with value "10.00"' on the control. Additional Details: 
    TechnologyName:  'Web'
    ControlType:  'Edit'
    Id:  'Amount'
    Name:  'Amount'

TagName:  'INPUT'
 ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0xF004F006
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Playback.PlaybackSettings.SendKeysAsScanCode = true;
```

This similar question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239673/exception-from-hresult-0xf004f006) lead to a go4answers topic which suggested the above.

"Playback by default sends keys to any application as Unicode. It might be necessary to send keys as scancode to certain applications. We can do this by using an over load of Keyboard.Sendkeys function."

From http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vstsqualitytools/archive/2010/04/13/uitest-framework-in-visual-studio-2010-part-2.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You could also try:

```
if (_page.AmountTextBox.Exists)
    {
        Mouse.Click(_page.AmountTextBox);
        Keyboard.Sendkeys("10.00");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion.   When I made this change, the textbox still only updated with the value sent when the script function was disabled.   Interestingly, though, the exception didn't get thrown  when the script was enabled; the keys just didn't seem to make it through the filter of the script.

Comment: Interesting! Did kida's suggestion work then? Maybe even a combo of the two. I wouldn't remove the javascript, but perhaps it can handle the key values differently? I know a lot more about coded ui than javascript though . . .

Comment: kida's solution did work, and from what I gathered from his explanation, it may explain why this one did not.   If the same default unicode values being sent through the "Text = ..." operation are being sent through the SendKeys operation as well, I guess that would explain why the string being sent never showed up in my text box.

Comment: I played around with this a bit more, and there's an overload in the Keyboard.Sendkeys method which includes an isUnicode argument.   When I set that to false, what you suggested worked for my needs.

Comment: Ah, I knew there was that overload, but couldn't find the documentation so I doubted myself! Glad you found it!