# Coded UI - "Cannot perform 'SetProperty' to textbox". Scheduled task runs test on remote server

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, coded-ui-tests

Scheduled Task run Coded UI test on a remote test server, which I normally access via a Remote Desktop connection. To keep screen unlocked I use  "tscon.exe RDP-Tcp#0 /dest:console" so my test starts fine, however it fails while setting value to the txtbox throwing exception:
**PlaybackFailureException exception:  Cannot perform 'SetProperty of Text with value**. If I connected to server with RDP Playback runs fine.

Have anyone ran into this problem and found solution?

Comment: I am getting mixed results out of the multiple runs where I see 50/50 pass/failed results. Will need to collect more data to understand nature of the issues with failing cases.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to:
[Coded UI Playback - error thrown when entering text in particular textbox (w/ javaScript filtering keystrokes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20669099/coded-ui-playback-error-thrown-when-entering-text-in-particular-textbox-w-ja)

Check that question and you may find your answer.

Comment: It's possible that it's a Unicode issue as mentioned by kida in the question listed above.

Comment: I don't think this is the same issue since my code never failed when remote screen is maxed. But thank you for the ref.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two possibilities

1. The textbox is not enabled and hence not accepting input
2. The max length of textbox is smaller than the length of the string you're trying to put in there

Comment: Thank you Naeem, I don't think it is boundary case since input is const and works all the time when remote screen is maxed. Thank you for your time.